# Rails Secrets returns boolean, but Rails ENV returns string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have a Ruby on Rails app in Heroku. On Heroku, I have an environment variable, for example, THIS_APP_IS_COOL and having a value of true. If I call ENV['THIS_APP_IS_COOL'], it'll return 'true' (string). In my Rails secrets (yaml-file), I have as below

```
this_app_is_cool: <%= ENV['THIS_APP_IS_COOL'] %>
```

When I call Rails.application.secrets.this_app_is_cool, it returns true (boolean) instead. Is this automatic conversion a Rails secrets thing? And what are some good practices to avoid this kind of thing?

Comment: This is related to the way YAML parses the values, same as for strings "yes" and "no" in YAML which get converted to booleans (https://makandracards.com/makandra/24809-yaml-keys-like-yes-or-no-evaluate-to-true-and-false